# Unavailable Shared Library - INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-emulator, package

I am taking over a project, and am trying to launch it in the Android Emulator. I get the following error in Logcat:

`11-11 06:21:42.215: ERROR/PackageManager(58): Package com.android.xxx requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing`!

Console displays:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

How can I make sure com.google.android.maps is included in my project?

UPDATE:
I am using a min sdk level of 3 in my androidmanifest.xml:

```
</application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you crate your emulated device, make sure you choose "Google APIs..." as the target. If you choose just "Android..." you won't have advanced APIs such as Maps available on the emulated device.

Comment: Can it be assumed that these APIs are available on all actual devices? Is it safe to use Google's mapview in any app for release on the Android Market?